# Trying to get property of non-object Yii

Tags: yii

I dont get this error, there is a row in database.

```
$tip = StringHelper::trimmer($_GET['tip']);
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM contact_reasons WHERE alias = "' . $tip . '"';
$model = ContactReasons::model()->findAllBySql( $sql );

die($model->id);

if(!is_null($model)) {
 $this->render('kontakt', array(
     'model' => $model,
 ));
} else {
 $this->renderText('Tražena stranica ne postoji.');
}
```

I used debug to see if there is a response, and even used query on database, and it returns a row with ID. I get this error on line with die();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that, `findAllBySql` returns an array of CActiveRecords, while `findBySql` returns a single CActiveRecord. You may also use parameter binding for your SQL statements to prevent SQL injection.

see also http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord